# is it possible to make VS designer refer to local dll instead of GAC on dev machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, gac

I'm working on a project which uses Infragistics components.

me and my fellow colleagues have the problem that we have different Versions of the infragistics in our GAC, which in turn results in a VS Designer doing odd things, creating errors because of the dll versions.

Since we don't want to be updating infragistics all the time, change the dll's in the project etc... we are searching for a solution where we make the designer refer to the dll's that are placed on a shared map. (using tortoiseSVN) and no longer from the GAC.

This would result in us updating infragistics on a machine but not facing version problems.

Things we already tried/Did:

- Setting Copy Local on True
- Setting Specific version on False
- created a shared map in the project which holds all the needed dll's. (Also previous versions). => This gives us the possibility to **Build** the project with previous dll's. This already works!

So shortly, is it possible to make a VS2012 project dll refer to a project dll at **Design** Time (not Build) and no longer to the GAC.